# I can SELECT from parameterized TVF in U-SQL but cannot CROSS APPLY

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I can select from a parameterized Table Value Function in U-SQL, but I can't seem to use it in a CROSS APPLY. See @query1 where I can do a basic select from my TVF. See @query3 for my workaround using SQL.MAP. See @query2 which doesn't work and is commented-out. Is this a supported pattern? The error returned is

> "C# error CS0103: The name 'temp' does not exist in the current context".

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.fn_convert;

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_convert(@temp decimal) /*temp in tenths of a degree Celsius */
RETURNS @result
AS
BEGIN
        @result =
        SELECT *
        FROM( VALUES
                 ("C", @temp / 10m) /* Celsius */
                ,("F", (@temp / 10m) * (9m / 5m) + 32m) /* Fahrenheit */
                ,("K", @temp / 10m + 273.15m) /* Kelvin */
            ) AS T([scale], [value]);
RETURN;
END;

@data =
    SELECT *
    FROM( VALUES
        (200), (220), (230)
    ) AS T(temp);

@query1 =
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.fn_convert(200) AS f;

OUTPUT @query1
TO "/Output/test1_fn_convert.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();

//doesn't work
//@query2 =
//    SELECT t.*
//    FROM @data
//    CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_convert(temp) AS t(scale, temp);
//
//OUTPUT @query2
//TO "/Output/test2_fn_convert.csv"
//USING Outputters.Csv();


@query3 =
    SELECT t.*
    FROM @data AS d
    CROSS APPLY EXPLODE(new SQL.MAP<string, decimal?>{{"C", d.temp / 10m}, {"F", (d.temp / 10m) * (9m / 5m) + 32m}}) AS t(scale, temp);

OUTPUT @query3
TO "/Output/test3_fn_convert.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the great repro.

What you are running into is that U-SQL (unlike T-SQL) currently does not support TVFs in `CROSS APPLY`. Unfortunately the error message is completely misleading in this case (I filed a bug to get the error message improved).

`CROSS APPLY` currently only takes one of the following expressions

1. `EXPLODE` on expressions (including C# UDF calls) that return either
   `SqlArray` and `SqlMap` (as in your workaround)
2. An instance of an
   `IApplier` UDO

Feel free to add a request to support TVFs in `CROSS APPLY` at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback. The reason why it is not supported at the moment has to do with the complexity of implementing `CROSS APPLY` against arbitrary U-SQL expressions in a scale-out environment efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Michael! I've submitted the feature request.